# Submitting a Database Value that includes Semicolon in String?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax, phpmyadmin

I have a standard Input Box that is submitting the value directly to the database, however including a semi-colon in the string is screwing up the DB Value.

**(Example 1) Text Input Value:**

```
<input type="text" id="security_check" value="a:1:{i:0;s:10:"1234567890";}">
```

**Database Value Result:**

```
security_check: s:28:"a:1:{i:0;s:10:"1234567890";}";
```

*You'll note that it adds s:28:" before and "; after*

When I wrap the value in brackets, it appears fine, but then the DB value includes brackets which doesn't work as it needs to be exact.

**(Example 2) Text Input Value:**

```
<input type="text" id="security_check" value="[a:1:{i:0;s:10:"1234567890";}]">
```

**Database Value Result:**

```
security_check: [a:1:{i:0;s:10:"1234567890";}]
```

Is there a way I can format the input value before submit, so that it appears in the DB with the semicolon included, exactly as originally written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using prepared statements or building your query dynamically and executing that? You can have this type of issue if you are not using prepared statement, and as well prepared statements reduce if not eliminate the possibility of SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I was able to accomplish this by posting the input value to the user_meta first, then running a prepared statement to update the Database within an array:

<?php 
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$key = 'security_check';
$single = true;
$user_security = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single );
$security = (array) $user_security;
update_user_meta($user_id, 'security_check', $security);
?>

Answer (score 0):

I think you have saved serialized data into database in serialize data string or serialize array counts added in front of string in database field

Comment: When I enter: a:1:{i:0  by itself in the text box for example (no semi-colon or quotes) it displays exactly as entered... I believe it is the inclusion of the semi-colon that is causing the undesired characters to appear.

Comment: <input type="text" id="security_check" value="a:1:{i:0;s:10:'1234567890';}">
try this by adding single quotation in inner string where you have user double quotation

Comment: Still giving the same result in DB = s:28:"a:1:{i:0;s:10:'1234567890';}";   The issue is the is the semicolon. Im wondering if there is something I can wrap the valur in that would not appear in the DB.